# Is there a good alternative for Lego elastic/rubber bands?

Tags: replacement-parts, rubber-bands

My son has got a few sets which include elastic bands, for suspension etc. however these seem to break and/or get lost. Is there a good alternative? Or is it best to just order them from Bricklink?

Comment: When I search for this before asking, I should have used the term "rubber band" rather than "elastic band", because the question has already be answered in detail here: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/14659/procuring-alternative-rubber-bands?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing that the [bands are quite cheap on Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=229), the best option is to buy original ones. They are guaranteed to have the proper dimensions, elasticity and friction. Maybe buy more to have spares and avoid paying for shipping multiple times when they break.

But in the end they are just plain rubber bands, so for most applications you can use any elastic you might happen to have at hand, as long as the properties are in the same ballpark.